# TikZ picture overlaps with text

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a TikZ picture that overlaps with the text. I'm sure this one is easy, but I didn't find a solution.

Here is a snapshot:

[image]

And this is the code:

```
\section{Algorithm Outline}

blabla

\begin{figure}[H]
\selectlanguage{american}%
\begin{centering}
\ttfamily  

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, 
auto, x=1cm, y=1cm,  transform canvas={scale=0.62},
>=stealth]  
    [picture code]

\end{tikzpicture}
\par\end{centering}

\selectlanguage{english}%
\caption{Algorithm Outline}
\end{figure}


The focus of this paper is on finding a feasible and good ....
```

I hope someone has a solution.

Comment: This is most likely because you're using `transform canvas`, which causes PGF to "[lose] track of positions of nodes and of picture sizes" (PGF manual). I would try setting `scale=0.62, every node/.append style={transform shape}`, but it's hard to test without some TikZ code.

Comment: What's the purpose of the two `\selectlanguage` commands? In the standard setup, `american` and `english` do exactly the same. Note also that `\centering` is not an environment; just put `\centering` instead of `\begin{centering}` and remove `\par\end{centering}`

Comment: @Jake: I tried your suggestion, unfortunately it does not work. Maybe there is another solution to scale the whole picture. Like in   pstricks, where one can set the unit to a value like 0.5cm.

Comment: @Chris: Yes, there's that option, and you're already using it to set your unit vectors to `1cm` length (which is the default value). Could you specify what you mean with "it does not work"?

Comment: @Jake: sorry for not being specific. I meant that there is no change, but in fact I made a mistake. Your solution does work! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7):

This happens because you're using transform canvas, which causes PGF to "[lose] track of positions of nodes and of picture sizes" (PGF manual).

Set `scale=0.62, every node/.append style={transform shape}` to use the "proper" way to scale your `tikzpicture`.