# Scaling Tikz picture without overlapping text

Tags: tikz-pgf, scaling

I have a simular issue to the question asked in : [TikZ picture overlaps with text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97725/tikz-picture-overlaps-with-text)
I have tried the solution provided by Jake. This makes that my picture fails to resize (scale) as i intend.

Whether i give `Set scale=0.4` or `Set scale=0.8` The size of the  picture remains the same

This is the code i use:

```
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[Set scale=0.4, every node/.append style={transform shape},]
% STYLES
\tikzstyle{every node}=[rectangle,rounded corners, minimum width=100pt,
    align=center,node distance=3cm,fill=black!10,inner sep=5pt,text width=3cm,minimum height=1.75cm,>=stealth,text badly centered]
% Draw forces
\node [force, above of=rivalry] (top) {Firm strategy, structure and rivalry};
\node [force, left=1cm of rivalry] (left) {Factor conditions};
\node [force, right=1cm of rivalry] (right) {Demand Conditions};
\node [force, below of=rivalry] (bottom) {Related and Supporting industries};
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Draw the links between forces
\path[<->,thick] 
(left) edge (right)
(left) edge (top)
(left) edge (bottom)
(top) edge (right)
(bottom) edge (right);
\path[<->,thick] 
(bottom) edge (top);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Porter's Diamond source:~\cite{Porter:1980}}%
\label{fig:diamond} 
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps this happens because the option is `scale=<some factor>` and not `Set scale=<some factor>`. Could you try with the right key and let us know if the problem is solved?

Comment: We prefer full compilable (but minimal) code example including a preamble. This way not everyone which wants to help you has to add the preamble him-/herself.

Comment: You are overwriting the `every node` style with the `\tikzstyle` command, you also need to append stuff with the [deprecated `\tikzstyle`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52372): `\tikzstyle{every node}+=[…]`. But you could just add it to the `every node` style options from the TikZ picture.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The option is `scale` and `transform shape` can<sup>*</sup> be given as direct option to `{tikzpicture}`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    scale=0.8,transform shape,
    % STYLES
    force/.style={%
        rectangle,rounded corners, minimum width=100pt,
        align=center,node distance=3cm,fill=black!10,inner sep=5pt,
        text width=3cm,minimum height=1.75cm,text badly centered
    },
    >=stealth,% had no effect in a node style ...
]
% Draw forces
\node (rivalry) {};% was missing!!
\node [force, above of=rivalry] (top) {Firm strategy, structure and rivalry};
\node [force, left=1cm of rivalry] (left) {Factor conditions};
\node [force, right=1cm of rivalry] (right) {Demand Conditions};
\node [force, below of=rivalry] (bottom) {Related and Supporting industries};
% Draw the links between forces
\path[<->,thick]
    (left) edge (right)
    (left) edge (top)
    (left) edge (bottom)
    (top) edge (right)
    (bottom) edge (right);
\path[<->,thick] (bottom) edge (top);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I had to add a node `(rivalry)` since it was missing in your example. Pleas use `\tikzset` (or the `{tikzpicture}` options as I did) and the `/.style` appendix. `\tikzstyle` is obsolete. Furthermore the `>=stealth` won’T have an effect inside a node style definition so I moved it …

---

<sup>*</sup> I was wrong and Qrrbrbirlbel’s comment on your question, mentions the real problem: `transform shape` can also be set only to `every node` but was overwritten in your example.

Comment: You were spot on. This worked